# Javascript not firing on select menu change 100% of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks to some help I received yesterday I've got some dynamic summing working on an HTML table based on user input and selections from a select menu. I've run into one problem though that's stumped me. If you look at my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/T5xtL/13/

if you enter data as follows:
Row 1: Fruit= Apple  Qty = 100
Rwo 2: Fruit= Banana  Qty = 200

Everything works as expected for the totals:

Total Apples    100
Total Bananas   200

If you now change Row 1 Fruit selection from Apple to Banance the sub totals are now:

Total Apples    100
Total Bananas   300

The Bananas total has updated correctly but the Apples total hasn't changed - it should now be zero/0.

Any ideas what this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Here's a [jsFiddle of what I meant since it was unclear before](http://jsfiddle.net/RhH52/1/)**

At the beginning of the calc function you should reset everything back to zero. The issue is that you only reset to zero if one of the fruits is selected in a drop down.  In your case apple wasn't selected so it was never reset! Hope this helps.

Comment: `var total = {};` seems properly reset at the beginning of each calc (before the iteration) for me.

Comment: That doesn't reset anything though.  That just creates a clear list if he never puts apple into it it will not update.  He needs to set total = {banana: 0, apple: 0, mangoes: 0] so that he can loop through and show them as zero. (or better yet just

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're only updating the `sum` that matches the `val`, in other words, you need to reset the values first. Add a class to your `span`s which hold the totals.

```
<span id="sumApples" class="sum"></span>
<span id="sumBanana" class="sum"></span>
...
```

And then reset:

```
for(val in total){
    if(total.hasOwnProperty(val)){
        $('.sum').html(''); // Reset
        $('#sum' + val).html(total[val]);
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your mistake:

```
for(val in total){
```

You're only setting the html for the properties of `total`, so as there are no `banana`s after you change the only `select` with `banana`, the `banana`s total won't be updated as `total['banana']` isn't set!

Here's a fix:

```
$('.fruit select:first option').each(function() {
    val = $(this).text();
    if(!total.hasOwnProperty(val))
        total[val] = 0;
});
```

This will grab all options from the first `select` and check if total has each of its options as properties, adding the lacking properties with value `0`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/T5xtL/21/)

If you want to check against all `select`s' `option`s, remove the `:first` from the selector.